# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I've problem which cannot fix. When I run my code I get these errors:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

My code is as follows:

```
def findMaxPages(userInlist):
    size = len(userInlist)
    readList = []
    if size == 0:
        result = (0, readList)
    if size == 1:
        readList.append(userInlist[0])
        result = (readList[0].getSumPage(), readList)
    if size > 1:
        dic0, dic1 = userInlist[0].getPagesDic(), userInlist[1].getPagesDic()
        exist=0
        for keys in dic0.keys():
            if keys in dic1: 
                exist+=1
        if exist == 0:
            nextUser = userInlist[0]
            withPage, withToTake = findMaxPages(userInlist[1:])
            withPage += nextUser.getSumPage()
            withoutPage, withoutToTake = findMaxPages(userInlist[1:])
            if withPage > withoutPage:
                readList.append(nextUser)
                result = (withPage, withToTake + readList)
            else:
                result = (withoutPage, withoutToTake)
    return result

pages, readerlist = findMaxPages(users)
```

"users" is a list whose elements are a Person object.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, min, max):
        self.name = name
        self.min = min
        self.max = max

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getMinPage(self):
        return self.min

    def getMaxPage(self):
        return self.max

    def getSumPage(self):
        return self.max - self.min + 1

    def getAllPages(self):
        allPages = []
        for pages in range(self.min, self.max + 1):
            allPages.append(pages)
        return allPages

    def getPagesDic(self):
        return createDic(self.getAllPages())
```

createDic() method returns the list in the parameter as a dictionary.

The algorithm is trying to do this: There are people who read pages from a particular book (min = the first page read from the book, max = the last page read from the book). Let's create a group of these people so that no one in the group reads a common page and the group reads the maximum number of pages.
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Add the complete error message.

Comment: We need to se line on which this error occured.

Comment: In case `size > 1` and `exist != 0` `result` will never be set.

Comment: You have different execution branches (the `if/else`s) and you don't define `result` in all of them. For example, what if `exist != 0`? Either add an `else` to all `if`s or define a default value **before** the `if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `result = None` in the very top of the `findMaxPages` function. That's the "easy" solution.

The more detailed part is that there are branches in your `if` statements where `result` is not defined at all. To make it accessible for the `return` statement, you need to make sure your variable was declared in **all** branches of `if/elif/else` statements.